# Graph theory problem.

Tags: graph-theory

In a country called Sevenland there are 15 cities. And every city has at least 7 highways connected to it. Prove that from any city we can go to any city using the highways

Comment: If the graph is disconnected there's a component with $\leq 7$ vertices, and within that the maximum degree is $6$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of showing that a graph has a Hamilton cycle if $\delta(G)\geq \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$, i.e. minimum degree (here 7) is greater or equal than half the number of vertices rounded down (here also 7). This is also known as Dirac's theorem, for a proof see e.g. here: [https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirac's_Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirac%27s_Theorem)
(This proof is typically covered in any graph theory introduction book.)

Answer (score 1):

We can convert this problem to a graphs and restate it as follows:

> Let $G$ be a simple graph with $|G| = 15$. If $d(v_i) \ge 7,\ \forall i \in \{1,2,...,15\}$, then $G$ is connected.

And to prove such an argument, suppose for a contradiction that $G$ is disconnected. Then $c(G) \ge 2$ where $c(G)$ is the number of components of $G$. But then by Pigeonhole Principle, one of these components has at most $7$ vertices. But we know that $G$ is simple and $d(v_i) \ge 7,\ \forall i \in \{1,2,...,15\}$. But in a component with at most $7$ vertices, we cannot have a vertex with degree $7$ since $G$ is simple; and this is a contradiction.

Comment: How do you deduce from the problem statement that the cities and highways of Sevenland can be modelled by the vertices and edges of a simple graph?

Comment: Yes, you are right actually. Just from the statement, there might be more than one highway from one city to another. But in that way, it would be obvious that this statement is false by putting all 7 highways between the same two cities. So, I kinda guessed how the statement meant to be asked.